# implement triggers in Slick

Tags: database, scala, slick

I have a table with foreign keys to several tables. Whenever I delete a row from that table, I want all rows in the child tables to be deleted first, and only then should the row in the father table should be deleted.

My first thought was to use a trigger, but I cannot seem to find this ability in Slick, which is the DB I'm using.

Is there a way to implement trigger capabilities in Slick?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't `ON DELETE CASCADE` in FK definition be enough in this case?

Comment: It would but I wanted to implement it myself to improve my control over the flow.

Comment: In this case I don't think that Slick provides an API for triggers, you'd have to create them using `sqlu` interpolator in raw SQL (DDL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use a DB triggers and functions by using plain SQL Queries in slick

```
 def checkCleared: DBIO[Int] = {

  sqlu"""  DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS funk() CASCADE;

          CREATE FUNCTION funk() RETURNS trigger
                LANGUAGE plpgsql
                AS '
              BEGIN
                IF OLD.cleared_can_load = FALSE AND NEW.cleared_can_load = TRUE
                THEN
                NEW.cleared_at = NOW() ;
                END IF;
                RETURN NEW;
              END;
            ';
              CREATE TRIGGER cleared
                            BEFORE UPDATE ON platform.product_settings
                            FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE funk();
            """
```

}

[Slick Plain SQL Queries docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/sql.html)

Then you can execute the plain sql queries by

```
   db.run(checkCleared)
```